# Under what circumstances will a Karate print statement not work?

Tags: karate

Under what circumstances will a Karate print statement not work?

As you can see in this screenshots, my `* print` statements are doing nothing.   My `logback-test.xml` is configured for DEBUG level on Karate packages.

I'm not sure why this is happening since I have other tests where this has always worked fine.   I'm using Karate 1.3.1.

[image]

Comment: no idea, most likely a log level hijacking by some other library. note that you can "switch off" logging in karate for some features via a tag or `configure`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#report-verbosity

Comment: Yeah, I think your right. I use Lombok logging setup.  I bet something is going on there.  I'll try to figure it out.   It stopped working after I imported some libs from Microsoft.  I'm not surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for the case where resolution cannot be found.

You can debug Karate steps by adding a line like this and then just looking at the console:

```
* java.lang.System.out.println(response2)
```